# Characterization of a $0$ function through Gaussian variables

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Let $X$ be a standard Gaussian random variable, $\varphi$ a bounded measurable real function and $O$ an open set of $\mathbb{R}$.

Let us assume that for all $x \in O$, $\mathbb{E}[\varphi(x+X)] = 0$. Can I conclude that $\varphi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in O$ (or at least for almost all $x \in O$)?

If $X$ is degenerate the answer is trivial but I struggle to show the above result.